# Fastest way to record audio macOS Big Sur?

Tags: macos, big-sur, quicktime

The fastest way I currently have is:

- <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>space</kbd>qui<kbd>enter</kbd> (Open QuickTime Player.app)
- <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> (close the Open dialog)
- <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>n</kbd> (New Audio Recording)

Is there already a faster way to prepare to record audio? Can I set up a faster method of opening an audio recorder? Or can I make the QuickTime Player experience less painful (for example by disabling the automatic Open dialog)

Answer (score 2):

From Mojave onwards, MacOS comes with a Voice Memos app, which may be faster and better-suited to your purpose.

Command N (or press the red button) will start a new recording.

You can also sync the recording using iCloud, if you want.

Alternatively, from Monterey onwards, you could use Shortcuts.app to create a Shortcut that records audio. It would then be available in the shortcuts menulet from the menu bar.

Comment: Can I customise the mic that voice memos uses? https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/434882/150109

Answer (score 1):

Using **Automator.app**, you can create a new "Quick Action" document. Next, add a "Run AppleScript" action to the Workflow and insert this following **AppleScript** code into the "Run AppleScript" action

```
tell application "QuickTime Player"
    activate
    set newAudioRecording to new audio recording
    start newAudioRecording
end tell
```

[image]

Next, save the new "Quick Action" document. (I saved it as "New QT Audio Recording"

Now you can assign it a keyboard shortcut in System Preferences.

[image]