# Change Voice Memos microphone to the non-system setting one

Tags: macos, big-sur, voice-memo

How can I change the Voice Memos microphone?

Even though [Voice Memos User Guide](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/voice-memos/vmaa4b813415/mac) says

> To create a recording, use the built-in microphone, a supported headset or an external mic

I can't see how can I choose which one to use.

QuickTime Player lets me choose the microphone to make new recordings with. I am not forced to use the system setting.

Can I customise Voice Memos to also use an input device of my choosing, that won't necessarily be the system setting?

Comment: What have you checked so far? System Preferences and input devices?